# How to count records in Ruby on Rails App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to to display all distinct records in a view. I have the following in my accounts_controler.rb file `@account = Account.count("created_at", :distinct => true)` or should I use `Account.distinct.count('date')`? If I read correctly rails 4 `:distinct => true` is now deprecated

I'm not sure if that is correct. Here is the entire controller file:

```
class AccountsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_account, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  respond_to :html

  def search
  if params[:search].present?
    @account = Account.search(params[:search])
  else
    @account = Account.all
  end
  end

  def index
    @account = Account.all.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)
    @account = Account.count("created_at", :distinct => true)
  end

end

  def show
    @notes = Note.where(account_id: @account.id) #Where a note belong to the current account
  end

  def new
    @account = Account.new
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @account = Account.new(account_params)
    @account.save
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def update
    @account.update(account_params)
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  def destroy
    @account.destroy
    respond_with(@account)
  end

  private
    def set_account
      @account = Account.find(params[:id])
    end

    def account_params
      params.require(:account).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :return_client, :program_id, :insurance_id, :address, :phone)
    end
```

I beleive there should be a ruby tag include in the index.html.erb file but I'm not sure of the syntax.

Comment: What's the question here?

Comment: grep for question marks

Comment: I learned something new from this question, +1ing for that. @FrederickCheung, it's how to count distinct fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `uniq` keyword to return all distinct records as follow:

```
def index
  @accounts = Account.uniq.order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per(10)

  @accounts_count = Account.uniq.count
end
```

and then you will have access to the instance variable `@accounts` in your `index.html.erb` file.

Comment: How would I display the results in index.html.erb?

Comment: I have edited my answer to give a correct answer. By using the keyword: `uniq`, you tell the db to return only unique records.

Comment: Then to display that count, I would place `<li><%= account.count %> </li>` in my index.html.erb file? I want to make sure I'm following you correctly.

Comment: <%= @accounts.count %>

Comment: I have a small issue. I'm using pagination and once I go past  10th record, then go to the next page the `<%= @accounts.count %>` start a new count. For example, once I go to page two the count is 2 instead of 12. Any thoughts?

Comment: so, you have 12 in all. do you want this count (12) on both page 1 and 2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. I want to count (12) on both pages.

Comment: I edited the answer. '@accounts_count' will always return count, while '@accounts' will return the paginated records.

Answer (score 3):

You are right.

Rails 3:

```
Account.count(:created_at, distinct: true)
```

Rails 4:

```
Account.distinct.count('date')
```

Comment: I never knew you could do this!